# How to Set Intra-site Replication Delay Time (Active Directory)

Tags: windows, active-directory, replication, windows-server-2019

Cannot configure replication delay. I have 2 domain controllers (DC1 and DC2, Windows Server 2019), both in the same site. I set the replication delay time in the Server Manager snap-in "AD Sites and Services" on DC2, but this setting does not help, yet controllers instantly exchange information about adding new users.  I can’t figure out why this is happening. Please tell me what I’m doing wrong.
[Server Manager snap-in "AD Sites and Services"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0GSN.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My mistake was that in the snap-in "AD Sites and Services" I set the settings for intersite replication.

For INTRAsite replication use utility repadmin in cmd, for example: `repadmin /notifyopt DC1 dc=xxx,dc=local /first:600 /subs:600`

Intrasite replication will now occur 10 minutes after the changes.
For more information, read the manual: `repadmin /?:notifyopt`

Comment: Then you should update the title of the post.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at the Inter-Site transport settings, which governs the replication interval between sites (Inter-Site replication), not within sites (Intra-Site replication).

If you want to change the Intra-Site replication interval you can make a registry change.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/modify-default-intra-site-dc-replication-interval

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn’t work on Windows Server 2019